# Как указать максимальную длину выводимой строки (Си)

Tags: c, строки

Добрый день!

Как при выводе на экран, с помощью переменной, указать максимальное количество символов, которые программа может вывести?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
int main(){
      char str[10];
      int n = 2;
      fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
      printf("%*.*s", n, n, str);
      return(0); 
}
```

Comment: В крайнем случае выводите посимвольно... Зависит от того, что и как вы выводить собираетесь. Строку можно просто обрезать, например...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если для вывода вы используете функцию `printf`, то вы можете написать следующим образом:

```
char s[] = "Hello";
printf( "%*.*s", 3, 3, s );
```

Или

```
int n = 3;

char s[] = "Hello";
printf( "%*.*s", n, n, s );
```

Comment: А если вводить строку с клавиатуры?

Comment: @Arden Какая разница откуда поступила строка? Вы же говорите о выводе строки в своем вопросе, а не о вводе.

Comment: Да я и сам понимаю, что разницы не должно быть. Тестирую код с fgets. Ошибок не выдаёт, но stdout пустой.

Comment: @Arden Может бть вы опять неправильно указали вызов fgets? Можете написать так printf( "%*.*s\n", n, n, s); То есть вставьте также вывод символа новой строки.

Comment: @Arden Надо для строк указывать форматный символ s, а не c. Символ c указывается, когда нужно вывести только один символ.

Comment: Да, всё получилось, спасибо